# Laravel :"php artisan db:seed" doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-seeding

I am try to run "ServiceTableSeeder" table in database  i got an error msg.

I try run "**`php artisan db:seed`**"

Msg:

```
[symfony\component|Debug\Exception\FetalErrorException]
cannot redeclare DatabaseSeeder::run()
```

**DatabaseSeeder .php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
     public function run()
     {
         Eloquent::unguard();
         $this->call('ServiceTableSeeder');

     }

}
```

**ServiceTableSeeder.php**

```
<?php

class ServiceTableSeeder extends Seeder {

  public function run()
  {
    Service::create(
      array(
        'title' => 'Web development',
        'description' => 'PHP, MySQL, Javascript and more.'
      )
    );

    Service::create(
      array(
        'title' => 'SEO',
        'description' => 'Get on first page of search engines with our help.'
      )
    );

  }
}
```

how to fix this issue .i am new in laravel anyone please guide me.

Comment: Try doing a `composer dump`.

Comment: I try "composer dump-autoload" but same error msg

Comment: I’m interested in your services. Can you get me on the first page of Google for “web design”?

Comment: @GobinathMahalingam You genuinely think you can get me to the top of Google for the phrase “web design”? 

Comment: @GobinathMahalingam White hot SEO techniques? I’m sold!

Comment: After a frustrating 20 minutes, I did 'touch 000-composer-du-after-adding' in the database/seeds directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that Service is a model you created, and that this model is inside the app folder, within the App namespace, try this:

Fix your ServiceTableSeeder.php header:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Service;

class ServiceTableSeeder extends Seeder {

  public function run()
  {
    Service::create(
      array(
        'title' => 'Web development',
        'description' => 'PHP, MySQL, Javascript and more.'
      )
    );

    Service::create(
      array(
        'title' => 'SEO',
        'description' => 'Get on first page of search engines with our help.'
      )
    );

  }
}
```

As you have moved your models to app\models, you must declare that in each model file:

Models.php:

```
 namespace App\Models;
```

And in your seed file, use:

```
 use App\Models\Service.php;
```

Are you using composer to autoload your files? If so, update your composer.json file to include your models location:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Models"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

And finally, run this in your command line:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: i try your step but i got "[symfony\component|Debug\Exception\FetalErrorException] class 'Service' Not found .   Pls guide me

Comment: @GobinathMahalingam I believe that you need to declare the namespace of the model. I included that in the answer.

Comment: @authur samarcos: I'm using laravel new version . I created models folder inside App folder. And created service model page. I try "use App\service;" and also "use App\models \Services" but I got same error msg

Comment: I think I make mistake to create models pls guide me

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is your `ServiceTableSeeder.php` file. You should make sure the class filename in this file is `ServiceTableSeeder` and not `DatabaseSeeder`

Comment: I added my "ServiceTableSeeder.php" pls guide me

Answer (score 2):

For those who are facing the same issue, confirm your APP_ENV variable from .env file cause Laravel don't let us to run db:seed if we set

> 'APP_ENV = Production'

for the sake of database records.

So, make sure you set value of APP_ENV to 'staging' or 'local' and then run php artisan db:seed